# Provide direct link to employer on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks, employers

I may be wrong, but up until recently, clicking the link of the employer when looking at a job posting took me to the employers site. Now it takes me to a listings by that employer.

While seeing the job postings of a company is helpful, I found going directly to their site VERY valuable, because I could evaluate the company a little bit based off their website content.

Please consider updating the employer link to go directly to their site, or maybe add a small link right next to their name to go to their website.

Comment: Looks like this was implemented. Link at the top of the listing goes to their direct site and a sidebar link exists to see more jobs from them. Thanks SO Team!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been changed back so that the employer name links to their website, if they entered one.  We moved the "all listings by this employer" to the bottom of the page and the sidebar.